# afterprint event on firefox 89

Tags: javascript, angular

Fragment that I have problem with:

```js
const afterPrint = () => {
    this.location.back();
    window.removeEventListener('afterprint', afterPrint);
};

window.addEventListener('afterprint', afterPrint);
window.print();
```

My goal is to redirect user back in history after print dialog has been closed (print or cancel)
On Chrome it works as it should but on Firefox 89 `afterprint` event is fired when page is dumped for printing when print dialog is still open.

[image]

Because the print dialog is still open, `this.location.back()` is blocked and doesn't work.

Tried it with firefox 83 previously and it worked as intended but after update I have noticed that it is not the case anymore.

Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Yes exactly the same issue! Doesn't happen in Chrome. That might be a bug introduced in recent Firefox versions, I use v88. You may want to open a ticket in their bug tracker.

Comment: Actually I've opened a ticket: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1728779

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution if anyone is curious

My solution was to place `this.location.back();` in `window.setTimeout` which is blocked from execution while print dialog is open.
After closing the print dialog I am redirected to the previous page as intended.

code:

```
const afterPrint = () => {
    window.setTimeout(() => {
        this.location.back();
        window.removeEventListener('afterprint', afterPrint);
    }, 1);
};

window.addEventListener('afterprint', afterPrint);
```

Comment: You cannot be sure that setTimeout is blocked always, unless the specification says so. But I think it doesn't.

Comment: @Rolf I haven't come up with better solution and this worked for me in every browser that I tested it so it is good enough for me. I'm open for ideas if anyone can think of something that will work better.